# Highcharts showing extra lables multiple times in x-Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I created a simple bubble chart using highcharts, with x-axis values are timestamps. Every thing working fine except the lables showing multiple same dates.

Created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anvk4y0o/

Code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
    },

    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d/%Y', this.value);
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        // data: [[1437415889539,36,79],[1437415899539,74,60],[1437515889539,76,58]]
        data: [{
            x: 1437416876595,
            y: 10,
            z: 34435
        }, {
            x: 1437503398847,
            y: 60,
            z: 24435
        }]
    }]
});
```

I just want to show what ever the x-values I have.

Thanks

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can define ticks by setting [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) and startOnTick / endOnTick. Other solution is using [tickPositions / tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner).

```
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick:true,
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/anvk4y0o/3/

Comment: Nice, oddly enough I feel like i looked in the docs for 15 minutes for those options and couldn't find them.

Comment: This helped me a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts will auto attempt to fill in a range of dates. Being as you have only provided data sets for those two dates the plugin is attempting to make a full chart but only has that range of dates to work with. Once you add a larger data set that spans a longer date range it should compensate. Until then you could add the option to show times. This would give you a broader view of what is happening in the chart.
[Documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats)

```
       xAxis: {
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
                second: '%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%H:%M',
                hour: '%H:%M',
                day: '%e. %b',
                week: '%e. %b',
                month: '%b \'%y',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', this.value);
                }
            }
        },
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anvk4y0o/2/)

Edit: In the demo you may need to make the results window larger so you can see the date_time labels properly.

Additionally you could attempt to use the [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickInterval) options to force the ranges to apply, or consider changing your timestamps to not include times, only the actual date.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to display just 2 dates ? I tried all the ways. but couldn't figure out

Comment: @testzuser Sebastian's answer provides all of the information you should need.